# GitLab: how to get the label added date by GitLab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm using GitLab 15.3.1 version and I'd like to obtain, using GitLab API, the label added date for a project issue.

This information is available from GitLab web browser interface as shown below

[image]

Is there any way to obtain that "11/10/2022 2.44pm" via API for that issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Label events for a single Issue with the [List project issue label events API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/resource_label_events.html#list-project-issue-label-events).

Here's an example using this [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/378378):

```bash
curl --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxTOKENxxx' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964/issues/378378/resource_label_events | jq '.'
```

Response:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 192875035,
    "user": {
      "id": 9671578,
      "username": "rzwambag",
      "name": "Roy Zwambag",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/9671578/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/rzwambag"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:51:15.420Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 17963221,
      "name": "application performance::active",
      "description": " Any issues that group::application performance has scheduled and is working on. They are in the build phase of the product development flow.",
      "description_html": " Any issues that group::application performance has scheduled and is working on. They are in the build phase of the product development flow.",
      "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
      "color": "#69D100"
    },
    "action": "add"
  },
  {
    "id": 192875036,
    "user": {
      "id": 9671578,
      "username": "rzwambag",
      "name": "Roy Zwambag",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/9671578/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/rzwambag"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:51:15.420Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 10690783,
      "name": "group::application performance",
      "description": "Issues belonging to the Application Performance group (formerly known as Memory) of the Enablement stage of the DevOps lifecycle. See https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/product/categories/#application-performance-group",
      "description_html": "Issues belonging to the Application Performance group (formerly known as Memory) of the Enablement stage of the DevOps lifecycle. See <a href=\"https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/product/categories/#application-performance-group\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer noopener\" target=\"_blank\">https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/product/categories/#application-performance-group</a>",
      "text_color": "#333333",
      "color": "#A8D695"
    },
    "action": "add"
  },
  {
    "id": 192875037,
    "user": {
      "id": 9671578,
      "username": "rzwambag",
      "name": "Roy Zwambag",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/9671578/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/rzwambag"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:51:15.420Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 15119514,
      "name": "type::maintenance",
      "description": "Upkeeping efforts and catch-up corrective improvements that are not Feature nor Bugs. Read more at https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/metrics/#work-type-classification",
      "description_html": "Upkeeping efforts and catch-up corrective improvements that are not Feature nor Bugs. Read more at <a href=\"https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/metrics/#work-type-classification\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer noopener\" target=\"_blank\">https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/metrics/#work-type-classification</a>",
      "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
      "color": "#330066"
    },
    "action": "add"
  },
  {
    "id": 192875043,
    "user": {
      "id": 1786152,
      "username": "gitlab-bot",
      "name": " GitLab Bot ",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/1786152/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-bot"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:51:16.579Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 25316145,
      "name": "devops::data_stores",
      "description": "Issues for the Systems stage of the DevOps lifecycle (Memory, Database, Global Search, Sharding)",
      "description_html": "Issues for the Systems stage of the DevOps lifecycle (Memory, Database, Global Search, Sharding)",
      "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
      "color": "#E44D2A"
    },
    "action": "add"
  },
  {
    "id": 192875044,
    "user": {
      "id": 1786152,
      "username": "gitlab-bot",
      "name": " GitLab Bot ",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/1786152/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-bot"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:51:16.579Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 14918396,
      "name": "section::enablement",
      "description": "Issues related to the Enablement section",
      "description_html": "Issues related to the Enablement section",
      "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
      "color": "#F0AD4E"
    },
    "action": "add"
  },
  {
    "id": 192875250,
    "user": {
      "id": 9671578,
      "username": "rzwambag",
      "name": "Roy Zwambag",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/9671578/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/rzwambag"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:52:13.714Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 2526320,
      "name": "workflow::in dev",
      "description": "Issues that are actively being worked on by a developer",
      "description_html": "Issues that are actively being worked on by a developer",
      "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
      "color": "#428BCA"
    },
    "action": "add"
  },
  {
    "id": 192875320,
    "user": {
      "id": 9671578,
      "username": "rzwambag",
      "name": "Roy Zwambag",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/9671578/avatar.png",
      "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/rzwambag"
    },
    "created_at": "2022-10-19T08:52:28.908Z",
    "resource_type": "Issue",
    "resource_id": 117155410,
    "label": {
      "id": 2526320,
      "name": "workflow::in dev",
      "description": "Issues that are actively being worked on by a developer",
      "description_html": "Issues that are actively being worked on by a developer",
      "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
      "color": "#428BCA"
    },
    "action": "remove"
  }
]
```